# Gtk3 Paned Widget default homogeneous sizes

Tags: pygtk, gtk3

I would like the default size for my two panes in the Paned widget to be equal width, or equal height.

Since there is no obvious setting for doing this, How can I correctly calculate this size?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the total size of the paned widget with `get_allocation()`, then set the position of the divider to be half that.

Depending on what UI you want, you can either do that once, or connect a handler after the `size-allocate` signal runs and keep recalculating it until the user adjusts it manually.

Comment: Mhm, my worry there is that the variable-width pane resize handle consumes an unknown width of space, so half of the parent won't be the correct size I figure. However you've given me the idea to sample both child widgets, sum and average them to get the widths they should be!

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this question while looking to solve the same problem, here is the approach I found in an example on some site (solution is for width, adapt for height as necessary):

```
hpane = Gtk.HPaned()
# hpane.set_wide_handle(True)
hpane.connect("size-allocate", self.hpane_resize_cb)
```

[...]

```
def hpane_resize_cb(self, widget, allocation):
    if allocation.width != 1:
        hpane_pos = 0.5 * allocation.width
    widget.set_position(int(hpane_pos + .5))
```

I'm still working on the code, and will be adding code so it stores any user modification and keeps the same proportion when resizing the window. But this should be enough to get others started on their solution.